# TextView append добавляет некоторые символы в начало строки

Tags: java, android-studio, textview

В попытке написать калькулятор я столкнулся с такой проблемой

```
                    if (!decimalSeparatorPresent){
                        outputField.append(".");
                        decimalSeparatorPresent = true;

                    }
```

При нажатии кнопки в конец выражения должна добавиться точка (**12.**), но она добавляется в самое начало перед старшим разрядом (**.12**), а при нажатии любой цифры после, всё становится на свои места (**12.4**), при чём все цифры всегда работают как надо при использовании того же append, я думал проблема в обновлении экрана или самого TextView, и попробовал использовать

```
outputField.refreshDrawableState();
```

и

```
outputField.invalidate();
```

Но это ни на что не повлияло

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Оказалось дело в том, что я неправильно настроил приведение текста в TextView к правому краю.
В свойствах TextView у меня было

```
android:gravity="start"
android:textDirection="rtl"
```

А необходимо было лишь

```
android:gravity="end"
```

Правда я не понял почему цифры и некоторые символы всё ещё работали правильно в предыдущем варианте